# Аппроксимация нейронной сетью

Tags: java, нейронные-сети

Подскажите возможно ли предсказывать значения функции (вроде экстраполяции) с помощью НС с обратным распространением ошибки? И в каком виде скармливать материал для обучения не совсем понял, нужно все десятичные цифры перевести в двоичные и подать на входы НС? Есть таблица х у, например:

```
х     у
2.2   4.4
6.2   8.4
10.2  12.4
14.2  ?
```

Хочу обучить НС, чтобы по значению х она находила у.

На всякий случай, НС, написанная по урокам https://github.com/BitterMurMur/TestMisc.git

Comment: Один входной нейрон (сюда подаем х) во входном слое, один в выходном (y) и один скрытый слой (количество нейронов зависит от сложности моделируемой зависимости). См. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%A6%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE

Comment: Это называется "регрессия". В большинстве двумерных случаев вполне себе решается без всяких нейросетей. Если очень хочется пострелять из пушки по воробьям - то можно и нейросеть прикрутить. Ни в какие двоичные цифры ничего переводить не надо, подаете набор "как есть", на выходе получаете модель (по сути - коэффициенты), связывающие Х и Y. А уже имея их -  делаете свое предсказание.